# Find all IRIs used in ontology which are not entities?

Tags: owl-api

Is there any straight-forward way in OWLAPI to find all IRIs used in an ontology which have not been identified as Entities i.e. have not been declared and are not used in a context which would allowed them to be identified as a specific entity type? Hoping for something analogous to OWLOntology.signature(), didn't see anything.

An example of that situation appears in BFO 2.0 (http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/bfo.owl) :

```
<rdf:Description rdf:about="http://example.com/bfo-spec-label">
    <obo:IAO_0000119>Person:Alan Ruttenberg</obo:IAO_0000119>
</rdf:Description>
```

Here `http://example.com/bfo-spec-label` is just a "bare" IRI of unknown entity type and thus does not appear in the ontology signature.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't find any elegant way to find all of these bare IRI's but these can be found by looking in all places they could possibly occur. A simple method would look like:
    private List findBareIRIs(OWLOntology onto) {
    List bares = new ArrayList();

```
// bare IRIs can occur as AnnotationSubjects, AnnotationObjects or the domain/range of AnnotationProperties
List<OWLAnnotationAssertionAxiom> asserts = OWLAPIStreamUtils.asList(onto.axioms(AxiomType.ANNOTATION_ASSERTION));
List<OWLAnnotationPropertyDomainAxiom> domains = OWLAPIStreamUtils.asList(onto.axioms(AxiomType.ANNOTATION_PROPERTY_DOMAIN));
List<OWLAnnotationPropertyRangeAxiom> ranges = OWLAPIStreamUtils.asList(onto.axioms(AxiomType.ANNOTATION_PROPERTY_RANGE));

//check the subject and values of each AnnotationAsertion
for (OWLAnnotationAssertionAxiom ax : asserts) {
  OWLAnnotationSubject subj = ax.getSubject();
  OWLAnnotationValue value = ax.getValue();
  if (subj.isIRI()) {
    bares.add((IRI) subj);
  }
  if (value.isIRI()) {
    bares.add((IRI) value);
  }
}
// check the domain and ranges of each AnnotationProperty
for (OWLAnnotationPropertyDomainAxiom ax : domains) {
  bares.add(ax.getDomain());
}
for (OWLAnnotationPropertyRangeAxiom ax : ranges) {
  bares.add(ax.getRange());
}

return bares;
```

}